# VBA Excel select content after the character occurrence

Tags: excel, vba

I want to select the content of my worksheet after the character occurrence in the row.

The code I have been using so far selects all the stuff after the offset.

```
 Sub Selection ()
 Dim Target_Start As Range, Target_End As Range

 Dim n as long

 Set Target_Start = work.Cells.Find("X", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns).Offset(1)
 Set Target_End = Target_Start.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)


 work.Range(Target_Start, Target_End).Select
 'Selection.EntireRow.Clear


 End Sub
```

[image]

What should I alter in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Select Used Range After a Cell

- If you want to allow a lower-case "`X`" then replace `True` with `False` (`MatchCase`).
- Note that this solution will include row 15 in your image which may be only formatted (borders, no values), because we are using `Used Range`. If you don't like that, you will have to use another way to define the range.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub selectAfter()
    Const sString  As String = "X"
    With work.UsedRange
        Dim rg As Range
        Set rg = .Find(sString, .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count), _
            xlFormulas, xlWhole, xlByRows, , True)
        If Not rg Is Nothing Then
            Dim Offs As Long: Offs = rg.Row - .Row + 1
            Set rg = .Resize(.Rows.Count - Offs).Offset(Offs)
            rg.Select
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. However, could you tell me, why can't I see here something like Clearcontents? I don't understand the code enough I am afraid.

Comment: I didn't know you wanted to clear the contents. Instead of `rg.Select` use `rg.ClearContents` or another flavor of `Clear`.